# Qt Creator hangs every time I open a class file

Tags: qt

I'm losing the will to live. Every time I open a class file in Qt Creator (3.0.1) it hangs for around 20-30 seconds, totally consuming the CPU core that it's running under. I tried changing pre-compiled header settings and deleting old settings files, but it still happens :(  So, has anyone had this issue and solved it?

Comment: reduce the amount of includes you have, the more unneeded ones the longer it takes

Comment: What is a 'class' file? What OS are you using?

Comment: I work in a large team on the same software solution, and I'm the only person that has this problem. Also, it started abruptly so I don't think it's anything to do with the number of headers.

Comment: I mean .cpp files. We're using Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Did you try to reset all your preferences?

Comment: Does this happen with every project?

Comment: I did reset all of my settings (as per this link http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-faq.html) and I also re-installed Qt Creator to a new location on the drive.Neither made any difference, sadly.

Comment: I only have access to the Example projects that come with the Qt SDK, and it doesn't seem to happen with those (although they are all very small and trivial). I tried deleting my shadow build directory and rebuilding in case it was a problem parsing those files but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade to QtCreator 3.3.0 - here the Qt team reworked the loading to use multiple threads and thus doesn't block the GUI while parsing the source and project files any more.

Comment: OK. Could you tell me if it's compatible with Qt 5.2.1? I'm unsure if the Creator is tied to the SDK version.